# Subsetting a data frame to include 20 rows before and after

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I know the title is kind of lame but I couldn't think of anything else to call this. I’m trying to subset a large data frame using the values that appear in the lon (longitude column). The current subsetting script I have works, and it creates subsets any time a -180 (the n/a value) appears, and includes the first non -180 number before and after one or more -180s is present. My problem is that I would like the subsets to be comprised of the 20 longitudes before any -180s, and 20 after. Since many of my files start with -180s and end with -180s this is creating and error. I just have no idea how to tell the script to subset -180s but also to ignore any that might appear in the first or last rows. Ideally the script would only subset -180s that have 20 longitudes before and 20 longitudes after them. Also, I will never know how many -180s might appear at the start and end of a file, which has been the biggest problem with figuring this out for myself. Below is a sample of my data and my current subsetting code. Thank you in advance for your help! **Edit:** It's also very important that the rows stay in the same order and are not sorted in any way as this is chronological data. And my data frame has 4461 rows and 7 columns. **Edit:** below is a small sample of my data frame.

```
 cols <- structure(list(fixType = structure(c(39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L), .Label = c("firstfix +indoors +startpoint", "firstfix +indoors +startpoint +cluster_center", "firstfix +indoors +stationary", "firstfix +indoors +stationary +cluster_center", "firstfix +invehicle +startpoint", "firstfix +invehicle +startpoint +cluster_center", "firstfix +invehicle +stationary +cluster_center", "firstfix +outdoors +startpoint", "firstfix +outdoors +startpoint +cluster_center", "firstfix +outdoors +stationary", "firstfix +outdoors +stationary +cluster_center", "inserted +indoors +midpoint", "inserted +indoors +pausepoint", "inserted +indoors +stationary", "inserted +indoors +stationary +cluster_center", "inserted +invehicle +midpoint", "inserted +invehicle +pausepoint", "inserted +invehicle +stationary", "inserted +invehicle +stationary +cluster_center", "inserted +outdoors +midpoint", "inserted +outdoors +pausepoint", "inserted +outdoors +stationary", "inserted +outdoors +stationary +cluster_center", "lastfix +indoors +endpoint", "lastfix +indoors +endpoint +cluster_center", "lastfix +indoors +stationary", "lastfix +indoors +stationary +cluster_center", "lastfix +invehicle +endpoint", "lastfix +invehicle +endpoint +cluster_center", "lastfix +outdoors +endpoint", "lastfix +outdoors +endpoint +cluster_center", "lastfix +outdoors +stationary", "lastvalidfix +indoors +stationary", "lastvalidfix +indoors +stationary +cluster_center", "lastvalidfix +invehicle +stationary", "lastvalidfix +invehicle +stationary +cluster_center", "lastvalidfix +outdoors +stationary", "lastvalidfix +outdoors +stationary +cluster_center", "unknown", "valid +indoors +endpoint", "valid +indoors +endpoint +cluster_center", "valid +indoors +midpoint", "valid +indoors +pausepoint", "valid +indoors +pausepoint +cluster_center", "valid +indoors +startpoint", "valid +indoors +startpoint +cluster_center", "valid +indoors +stationary", "valid +indoors +stationary +cluster_center", "valid +invehicle +endpoint", "valid +invehicle +endpoint +cluster_center", "valid +invehicle +midpoint", "valid +invehicle +pausepoint", "valid +invehicle +startpoint", "valid +invehicle +startpoint +cluster_center", "valid +invehicle +stationary", "valid +invehicle +stationary +cluster_center", "valid +outdoors +endpoint", "valid +outdoors +endpoint +cluster_center", "valid +outdoors +midpoint", "valid +outdoors +pausepoint", "valid +outdoors +pausepoint +cluster_center", "valid +outdoors +startpoint", "valid +outdoors +startpoint +cluster_center", "valid +outdoors +stationary", "valid +outdoors +stationary +cluster_center"), class = "factor"), lon = c(-180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180), lat = c(-180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180, -180), activityIntensity = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L), Impute = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4352L, 4353L, 4354L), subsetNum = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("fixType", "lon", "lat", "activityIntensity", "Impute", "ID", "subsetNum"), row.names = c(4462L, 4463L, 4464L, 4465L, 4466L, 4467L, 4468L, 8813L, 8814L, 8815L), class = "data.frame")
```

Subset code:

```
set.seed(5)
n <- length(df) #make it equal to the length of whatever the input file is

impCols <- df[ , c("fixType", "lon", "lat", "activityIntensity", "Impute", "ID", "subsetNum")]

test.df <- data.frame(impCols)

df <- test.df
obs <- dim(df)[1]

counter <- 1
subM.List <- list()

start.idx <- NA

for(i in 1:obs){
    if (is.na(start.idx) & (substr(df[i,"lon"], 1, 4) == -180)){
      start.idx <- i-1
  }
  else if (!is.na(start.idx) & (substr(df[i,"lon"], 1, 4) != -180)){
    end.idx <- i+1 #the plus one will give you the first two instances of signal instead of just the first
    subMat <- df[start.idx:end.idx,]
    subM.List[[counter]] <- subMat
    start.idx <- NA
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using something like `max(i, 20)` and `min(i, nrow(data))` to start/end the selection of your 20 rows.

Comment: @EllisValentiner I should have also mentioned that the order of the rows is chronological, and for my application it's very important that the order of the rows be preserved. I'm currently trying min and max, but I think it will likely change the order of my rows.

Comment: Here, `diff(lon==180)` is your friend.   If you could kindly post [a reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro) specifically for the `df` data, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Your example `lon` has neither 7 nor 4461 values. Is it a partial column from your dataset?    In any case, either Ricardo's `diff` or  similarly `which(df$lon !=180)` will get you started.  Once you know the row indices of the transition from "180" to "not 180", it's easy to add or subtract 20 from those indices to get the subset you want.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, sorry, that's just one column out of 7 in my data frame, I'm working on adding a reproducible example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
indicators <-  df$lon == -180

# the first and last non-zero indicators are your index boundaries
indx.min <- min(which(!indicators))    # will issue warning if lon is nothing but '-180'
indx.max <- max(which(!indicators))    # will issue warning if lon is nothing but '-180'

"My problem is that I would like the subsets to be comprised of 
    the 20 longitudes before any -180s, and 20 after"


# `inPlay` are the indicators that are not at the extreme ends
inPlay <- which(indicators)
inPlay <- inPlay[inPlay > indx.min & inPlay < indx.max]

# Sample Size
S <- 20  # use a variable so you can change it as needed

diffPlay <- diff(inPlay)
stop <- c(which(diffPlay !=1 ), length(inPlay))
start <- c(1,   which(diffPlay !=1 )+1)

# these are your rowranges of `180s`.  You can have a look if youd like
rbind(inPlay[start], inPlay[stop])

# we are going to take the 20 rows before each "start"
#   and the 20 rows after each "start" + "plus"
inPlayPlus <- inPlay[stop] - inPlay[start]
inPlayStart <- inPlay[start]

## The names given to `inPlay` will be the name of your subsetted list
names(inPlayStart) <- ifelse(inPlayPlus > 0, paste0("Rows", inPlayStart, "_to_", inPlayStart+inPlayPlus), paste0("Row", inPlayStart))

subsetsList <- 
  lapply(seq_along(inPlayStart), function(i) {
      # This can be one line.  Broken up so you can see what's happening
      from <- max(indx.min, inPlayStart[[i]]-S) # notice, calling max on the min
      to   <- min(indx.max, inPlayStart[[i]] + inPlayPlus[[i]] +S) #    and  min on the max

      cat("i is ", i, "\tPlus=", inPlayPlus[[i]], "\t(from, to) = (", from, ", ", to, ")\tDIFF=", to-from, "\n", sep="")
      indx <- if (inPlayPlus[[i]] == 0) from:to else setdiff(from:to, inPlayStart[[i]]+(1:inPlayPlus[[i]]) )
      df[indx, ] 
    })


## Have a look at the results
subsetsList
```

Comment: Yeah, right: snitch from my comment :-) .  But, on the serious side, this answer only finds one block of rows bounded top&bottom by -180, doesn't it?  I'm guessing that out of 4600 rows, there are several such blocks, so you'll need to locate more than just the `min` and `max` of `indicators` I think.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, have a look at the `lapply` statement.  It iterates over each occurrence of -180.  The sole purpose of the min/max is to exclude  any starting/ending series.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta This ran, but it gave me 335 subsets (out of 4461 rows) which is too many, and each subset was composed of 41 rows that were just a series of na. Not sure what's wrong yet, but I'm trying some different things.

Comment: @KMess., I am confused.  You asked for each subset to contain 41 rows (20 before + 1 + 20 after = 41).  Incidentally, your exact request is quoted in my answer

What output would you expect?   It sounds like you have 335 `-180`'s out of 4461 values.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, so sorry, I thought I was being clear. Usually the -180s occur in groups, so I would like the entire group of -180s to be subsetted along with the 20 non-180s before and the 20 non-180s after. An example of a subset would be, -117.2229 -117.2232 -117.2232 -117.2232 -117.2232 -117.2232 -117.2231 -117.2226 
-117.2228 -117.2229 -117.2227 -117.2229 -117.2229 -117.2229 -117.2229 -117.2229 -117.2229 -117.2229 -117.2229 -117.2229
-180.0000 -180.0000 -180.0000 -117.2229 -117.2232 -117.2232 -117.2232 -117.2232 -117.2231 -117.2226 -117.2229 -117.2229 (up to 20)

Comment: @KMess. In the comments to your question, I posted a link to a question about producing a minimally reproducible example.  There is a reason that folks on SO ask for that.   You posted data and nothing in the data reflected the point that the `180`'s occur in batches in the middle of the data

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, I'm really sorry, I'm pretty new to this and still finding my way.

Comment: @KMess. it's not a problem.  My point was merely that the request for a good example is not a trivial one.   Anyway, as for your problem, finding a sequence of occurring numbers is more complicated.  Please see the edited code as it should work

Comment: This works great! Thanks so for your time and sorry for the unnecessary stress!

Comment: Oops, sorry for missing the `lapply` discriminator there.