# Extract n rows before and after a value in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame with certain values in a `Mark` column. I want to extract `n` values before and after a mark occurs (including the row with the mark).

I find the values I need by using `indices <- which(df$Mark == 1)` where `1` is the value I'm looking for. Now I need for example the indices of 5 rows before that and 5 rows after (and the one with the mark, so 11 rows in total).

I was thinking about looping through the `indices` to increase and decrease it by `n`, and then to subset the data frame with the appended `indices`. It would be quite nasty though.

Is there a faster way to do it? e.g. in dplyr? Base R answer will be fine as well.

PS: I read the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063504/subsetting-a-data-frame-to-include-20-rows-before-and-after?rq=1) but it doesn't seem to fit my problem.

Here's the `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(CH1 = c(-0.02838132, -0.02642141, -0.02511601, 
-0.02443906, -0.02414024, -0.02417388, -0.02451562, -0.02393946, 
-0.02242496, -0.02104852, -0.0198534, -0.018965, -0.01853905, 
-0.01837877, -0.01857743, -0.01847437, -0.0176798, -0.01672419, 
-0.01594565, -0.01522826, -0.01485198, -0.01484227, -0.01507997, 
-0.01556828, -0.01534458, -0.01473233, -0.01376753, -0.01251296, 
-0.0116294, -0.01064516, -0.00966026, -0.00970934, -0.00969434, 
-0.00921217, -0.00881855, -0.00832315, -0.00793322, -0.00718289, 
-0.00643288, -0.00574532, -0.00535603, -0.00503564, -0.00469125, 
-0.00449608, -0.00426023, -0.00406978, -0.00401041, -0.00293273, 
-0.00154294, -0.0012401, -0.00108466, -0.00116468, -0.00121755, 
-0.00127168, -0.00099938, 0.00017319, 0.0019737, 0.00333815, 
0.00396771, 0.00439491, 0.00482015, 0.00515174, 0.0054591, 0.00657748, 
0.00863549, 0.01048496, 0.01175601, 0.01272887, 0.01350854, 0.0140988, 
0.01475749, 0.01568579, 0.0178412, 0.02036553, 0.02206326, 0.02315541, 
0.0241971, 0.02509713, 0.02599812, 0.02695202, 0.02829221, 0.03048931, 
0.03233365, 0.03385062, 0.03544046, 0.03690707, 0.03846173, 0.03980747, 
0.04145224, 0.04344824, 0.04491818, 0.04621653, 0.04728952, 0.04851875, 
0.04968494, 0.05085734, 0.05207405, 0.05288386, 0.05377864, 0.05486108, 
0.05593761, 0.0570737, 0.05811917, 0.0593426, 0.06005302, 0.05993605, 
0.05984828, 0.06032347, 0.06089914, 0.06177185, 0.06246712, 0.06323557, 
0.06413276, 0.06416812, 0.06303713, 0.06264461, 0.06301019, 0.06348586, 
0.06426832, 0.06509175, 0.06570335, 0.06598329, 0.06489886, 0.06344099, 
0.06281661, 0.06292738, 0.0630922, 0.06334323, 0.06376194, 0.0640305, 
0.06399924, 0.06292669, 0.06141425, 0.06046086, 0.06002845, 0.05977921, 
0.05952547, 0.05947563, 0.05888767, 0.05753626, 0.05571093, 0.05391346, 
0.053135, 0.05240138, 0.05196891, 0.05157123, 0.05107314, 0.05004111, 
0.04812315, 0.04601065, 0.04457145, 0.04376672, 0.04318091, 0.04265054, 
0.04222059, 0.041618, 0.0403326, 0.03810122, 0.03623468, 0.03515417, 
0.0343935, 0.03381848, 0.03330182, 0.03288956, 0.03268627, 0.03136984, 
0.02941283, 0.02847409, 0.02766387, 0.0268678, 0.02645577, 0.02606292, 
0.02592612, 0.0258327, 0.02477442, 0.02381663, 0.02342893, 0.02307516, 
0.02289283, 0.02281655, 0.02268435, 0.02245292, 0.02224212, 0.02203094, 
0.02189966, 0.02157357, 0.02129673, 0.02102508, 0.02140636, 0.02188274, 
0.02238155, 0.02332248, 0.02454547, 0.02617604, 0.0281874, 0.03046315, 
0.03274331, 0.03508138, 0.03754183, 0.04001183, 0.04252412, 0.04485972, 
0.04726444, 0.04945699, 0.05171933, 0.05405642, 0.05621058, 0.05858717, 
0.06119974, 0.0631874, 0.06494498, 0.06654966, 0.06778654, 0.06895418, 
0.0702159, 0.07208018, 0.07471886, 0.07640609, 0.07795521, 0.07929013, 
0.08029186, 0.08135373, 0.08218034, 0.08313267, 0.08513113, 0.08683419, 
0.08791834, 0.08894015, 0.08975692, 0.09043255, 0.09113128, 0.09186111, 
0.09291916, 0.09414985, 0.09492029, 0.09583852, 0.09664483, 0.09738685, 
0.09791321, 0.09827693, 0.09842386, 0.09819575, 0.09783525, 0.09711579, 
0.09588714, 0.09464117, 0.09342161, 0.09221725, 0.09094498, 0.08979087, 
0.08813678, 0.08722136, 0.08660734, 0.0863056, 0.08614786, 0.08576027, 
0.08508192, 0.08408207, 0.08224716, 0.0805236, 0.0793857, 0.07835744, 
0.07776693, 0.07704602, 0.0762578, 0.0748622, 0.07237066, 0.06983608, 
0.06798425, 0.06677078, 0.0660528, 0.06569698, 0.06521391, 0.06434717, 
0.06249718, 0.06009818, 0.05800739, 0.05674874, 0.05583431, 0.05525231, 
0.05479279, 0.05451269, 0.05392969, 0.05218898, 0.05015828, 0.04889652, 
0.04834132, 0.04789649, 0.04757991, 0.04729923, 0.04713846, 0.04664839, 
0.044963, 0.0434754, 0.04290805, 0.04229798, 0.04186826, 0.04133299, 
0.04069157, 0.03980917, 0.03850414, 0.03609292, 0.03422226, 0.03281199, 
0.03131085, 0.03030436, 0.02957696, 0.02881902, 0.02801267, 0.0266918, 
0.02524513, 0.02468021, 0.02422629, 0.02412119, 0.02414609, 0.02431383, 
0.02445115, 0.02420395, 0.02307613, 0.0225228, 0.02239294, 0.02228146, 
0.02247078, 0.02297619, 0.02339916, 0.02380192, 0.02367893, 0.02331219, 
0.02357285, 0.0239001, 0.02413282, 0.02442478, 0.02460252, 0.02484779, 
0.02539408, 0.02547098, 0.02568989, 0.02612677, 0.02653343, 0.02691505, 
0.02732947, 0.02783551, 0.02845577, 0.0294369, 0.03000503, 0.0303594, 
0.03106044, 0.03183592, 0.03254643, 0.03336877, 0.03433665, 0.03611183, 
0.03759354, 0.03864425, 0.03966344, 0.04067133, 0.04175726, 0.04283931, 
0.04391302, 0.04588513, 0.04825597, 0.04982677, 0.05137081, 0.05256286, 
0.05363528, 0.05468207, 0.05576433, 0.05764562, 0.06039843, 0.06209074, 
0.06330606, 0.06437107, 0.06532845, 0.06612719, 0.06689882, 0.06780636, 
0.06962782, 0.07139035, 0.07266567, 0.07378628, 0.07471222, 0.07541681, 
0.07637413, 0.07729325, 0.07797043, 0.07928976, 0.08020929, 0.08104116, 
0.08185486, 0.08268223, 0.08352671, 0.08418175, 0.08467345, 0.0845037, 
0.08452599, 0.08504328, 0.08524517, 0.08562133, 0.08602719, 0.08630189, 
0.08619381, 0.08511638, 0.08378159, 0.08298928, 0.08275849, 0.08255187, 
0.08253576, 0.08248511, 0.08237054, 0.08131169, 0.07927644, 0.07758952, 
0.07666323, 0.07611373, 0.07583219, 0.07563592, 0.07526416, 0.07413918, 
0.07218219, 0.07052977, 0.06947646, 0.06885928, 0.06852632, 0.06836134, 
0.06829559, 0.06804968, 0.06684561, 0.06508074, 0.06383415, 0.06333059, 
0.06309205, 0.06312215, 0.06308869, 0.06325907, 0.06330066, 0.06230686, 
0.06121331, 0.06093323, 0.06080826, 0.06103985, 0.06129866, 0.0616675, 
0.06222659, 0.06271791, 0.06269919, 0.06317165, 0.06388476, 0.06443688, 
0.06532656, 0.06643683, 0.06762666, 0.0688545, 0.06957003, 0.07049679, 
0.07145847, 0.07254429, 0.07379688, 0.07520389, 0.07666438, 0.07813754, 
0.07980724, 0.08164999, 0.08337331, 0.0850293, 0.08675431, 0.08850279, 
0.0903589, 0.09223478, 0.09399396, 0.09617301, 0.09825616, 0.1001754, 
0.10215286, 0.10405939, 0.10593522, 0.10771114, 0.10955779, 0.11137673, 
0.11350922, 0.11566091, 0.11786379, 0.1201627, 0.12245044, 0.12446617, 
0.12668717, 0.12880468, 0.13083965, 0.13320723, 0.13573529, 0.13813868, 
0.14067729, 0.14306904, 0.14548148, 0.14758988, 0.14929967, 0.150388, 
0.15233791, 0.15449043, 0.15652253, 0.15867107, 0.16075753, 0.16281015, 
0.16490422, 0.16620035, 0.16787185, 0.16964339, 0.17125645, 0.17307489, 
0.17497104, 0.1767696, 0.17835094, 0.1791379, 0.17976147, 0.18114665, 
0.18252681, 0.18401302, 0.18556376, 0.18716799, 0.18869627, 0.18947925, 
0.18952475, 0.19017635, 0.19119224, 0.19240457, 0.19406083, 0.19560736, 
0.19702311, 0.19838278, 0.19857232, 0.19853884, 0.19905365, 0.19978584, 
0.20052382, 0.20136617, 0.20214938, 0.20287189, 0.20312707, 0.20246537, 
0.20244905, 0.20259959, 0.20278233, 0.20327239, 0.20340601, 0.20375103, 
0.20409654, 0.2038635, 0.20327988, 0.20336974, 0.20360702, 0.20394714, 
0.20437293, 0.20460138, 0.20475748, 0.20456536, 0.20375752, 0.20371552, 
0.20368604, 0.20359299, 0.2035453, 0.20345831, 0.20340526, 0.20343742, 
0.20276403, 0.20228943, 0.20203541, 0.20188482, 0.2018925, 0.20187522, 
0.20192079, 0.20182329, 0.20151561, 0.20119683, 0.20101932, 0.20076922, 
0.20026171, 0.19982927, 0.19950271, 0.19908488, 0.19889168, 0.19908054, 
0.19908604, 0.19869895, 0.1984064, 0.1980564, 0.19761464, 0.19729775, 
0.19710955, 0.1974078, 0.19742712, 0.19735026, 0.19726095, 0.19695149, 
0.19679484, 0.19663087, 0.19647489, 0.19718868, 0.19785891, 0.19784996, 
0.19788255, 0.19757998, 0.19728665, 0.19721918, 0.19730429, 0.19846697, 
0.19968045, 0.19982629, 0.20010276, 0.20030209, 0.20027906, 0.2004303, 
0.20071957, 0.20170523, 0.20357136, 0.20445201, 0.20511229, 0.2053825, 
0.20552762, 0.2057181, 0.20584874, 0.20681113, 0.20865934, 0.20982285, 
0.21037306, 0.21086055, 0.21114743, 0.21141832, 0.21172704, 0.21270722, 
0.21425499, 0.21508047, 0.21540311, 0.21570137, 0.21566178, 0.2157706, 
0.2157407, 0.21586709, 0.21686926, 0.21775885, 0.21800305, 0.21835183, 
0.21890219, 0.21994038, 0.22143123, 0.22224599, 0.22288845, 0.22398168, 
0.22474541, 0.22512311, 0.22491746, 0.2245485, 0.22401106, 0.22340615, 
0.22256076, 0.22140816, 0.22045675, 0.21932106, 0.21813713, 0.21674703, 
0.21546952, 0.21415956, 0.21265213, 0.21120454, 0.20967419, 0.2082095, 
0.20655277, 0.20475774, 0.20279387, 0.20076135, 0.19890919, 0.19709851, 
0.19524029, 0.19323021, 0.19112383, 0.18902898, 0.18701997, 0.18506767, 
0.18315709, 0.18136762, 0.17967033, 0.1778329, 0.17634939, 0.17506276, 
0.17422849, 0.17365934, 0.17368531, 0.17453934, 0.17546247, 0.17564483, 
0.17587478, 0.17576717, 0.17500107, 0.1736709, 0.17258336, 0.17265072, 
0.17284319, 0.17171922, 0.16994849, 0.16780928, 0.16595082, 0.16508843
), Mark = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("CH1", 
"Mark"), row.names = c(NA, 700L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `as.vector(sapply(indices, function(x) (x-5):(x+5)))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `dplyr`, you can use indexing in `base` R.

```
inds = which(df$Mark == 1)
# We use lapply() to get all rows for all indices, result is a list
rows <- lapply(inds, function(x) (x-5):(x+5))
# With unlist() you get all relevant rows
df[unlist(rows),]
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but how can we get rid of negative row index inside the lapply?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a similar problem with the shift function from data.table. Basically I use shift in the i statement of the data table:

```
library(data.table)

df[Mark == 1 | shift(Mark==1, n=5L, type = "lag") | shift(search==1, n=5L, type = "lead")]
```

I always find data.table to be really intuitive.